# Displaying Charts - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I am trying to display charts i.e Line chart in my angular 2 application. But i am very new to how charts are being displayed. I am following the documentation from valor software but i am not getting a good result. There is an error  showing up in my console . I have imported the **ChartsModule** in my **app.module.ts**. What must i do right to the line chart?

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="display: block;">
    <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels">{{label}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
        <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index">{{d && d.data[j]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button (click)="randomize()">CLICK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**dashboardComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'line-chart-demo',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.html'
})
export class LineChartDemoComponent {
  // lineChart
  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
    {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C'}
  ];
  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true
  };
  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ];
  public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line';

  public randomize():void {
    let _lineChartData:Array<any> = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
      _lineChartData[i] = {data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label};
      for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
        _lineChartData[i].data[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      }
    }
    this.lineChartData = _lineChartData;
  }

  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"

       ],
```

**error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.1166.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:4:38)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.1166.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.519 (chart.js?7d5f:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 48f1b30…:52)
    at Object.1215 (addScript.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 48f1b30…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 48f1b30…:23)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
```

Comment: Looks like you're using webpack which usually fixes this issue as require() isn't available on the client side of javascript, however there is probably something wrong with your webpack.config.js file? Could you post it in your question as I believe that will be where your issue is and someone who is better at webpack than me will be able to find it

Comment: @BenYeomans, i don' have any file named webpack in my folder

Comment: try adding <script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script> to your dashboard.html or <script src="scripts.bundle.js"></script> if the first one doesn't work, can you put a link to what documentation you're following?

Comment: the chart doesn't show although no error in the console now. This is the documentation http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include `<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>`  in your dashboard.html.
2. Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>` to your index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

initially you have to install chart.js

```
npm install ng2-charts chart.js --save

once it's done need to import it in your app.module.ts file
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
@NgModule( declarations: [],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
ChartsModule,
```

])

**These charts are depend on C3 so have to include it also**

```
 npm install c3
```

Final thing which you have missed it you also have to add style u**nder 
  angular.cli.json**

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/c3/c3.min.css"
  ],
```